# MS SQL - Replacing ID values in a query with values from another table

Tags: sql-server

Hopefully I have this explained correctly.  This is all new for me.

I have two tables that I'm trying to get the data from.  One is **dbo.geographic** that has two columns, **map_id** and **map_name**.  These two columns contain the country, state, and city levels for data.

The other table is **dbo.orders**.  The columns I'm interested in are **country_id**, **state_id**, and **city_id**.  These columns just have their corresponding numbers from the **dbo.geographic** table.

I'm trying to run a query that takes the **country, state, and city** values from **dbo.order** table and replaces them with correct string from the **map_name** column of dbo.geographic.  Like I said, I'm new to messing with SQL, and I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm missing here (I'm sure it's a simple fix).  I've been able to get this to work when it's one column to one column, but it hasn't worked when I tried to get it to go from one column to three.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT country.map_name, state.map_name, city.map_name, orders.other_columns
FROM orders
JOIN geographic AS country ON country.map_id = orders.country_id
JOIN geographic AS state ON state.map_id = orders.state_id
JOIN geographic AS city ON city.map_id = orders.city_id
```

Essentially, you join with `geographic` three times, under different aliases, matching the appropriate column from the `orders` table with the `map_id`

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  I understood how to join the different tables, but I get now what exactly is happening when I do that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pleased to have helped. Any time :-)